# Ruby: How to find if a string of round/curly/square braces is valid?

Tags: ruby

I was just given this array of strings:

```
expressions = [ ")(){}", "[]({})", "([])", "{()[]}", "([)]" ]
```

I'm supposed to write a function that prints 0 for each invalid string, and prints 1 for each valid string. So the ouput of this function given `expressions` as an argument is `0 1, 1, 1, 0`

How would I do this?

```
def check_braces(expressions)
  # ??
end
```

== UPDATE ==

From Peter's hint I came up with an answer:

```
expressions = [ ")(){}", "[]({})", "([])", "{()[]}", "([)]" ]
# expressions = [ "[]({})" ]

def check_braces(expressions)
  matchers = {
      "{" => "}",
      "[" => "]",
      "(" => ")"
      }

  expressions.each do |expression|
    elements = []
    expression.chars.each do |char|
      elements << char if elements.empty?
      last_element = elements[-1]
      if char == matchers[last_element]
        elements.pop
      end
    end
    puts (elements.empty? ? 1 : 0)
  end
end

check_braces(expressions)
#0
#1
#1
#1
#0
```

Comment: What constitutes a valid string?

Comment: @Linuxios he is looking for matching opening and closing brackets. so `()` is valid where as `[(])` is invalid because the closures do not match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the basic idea, and I will leave the implementation to you. For each of those strings,

1. loop through its characters;
2. when you see a `{[(`, put it into a stack (Ruby array can work as a stack);
3. when you see a `}])`, take a look at the last character in the array and see whether it is a match (for example, the last element in the array is `[`, and you have a `]`, that's a match). If it is a match, pop the last element in the array; any time you see one mismatch, the string is bad, and you can stop the loop.

Comment: nice i get it! I'll try it out

Comment: WOW I spent an hour on this question and got no where. After your explanation it took me 2 minutes to figure it out THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem with your code is that it won't catch something like this `"[]({)"`.

If you add an elsif check to see if the current char is already in the elements array and shovel it on if it isn't, that should solve it:

```
if char == matchers[last_element]
    elements.pop
  elsif !elements.include? char
    elements << char
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a case where this doesn't work `{([)]}`, which I attached to the end of the expressions array.

Here is my solution and I shortened it up a bit.

```
expressions = [ ")(){}", "[]({})", "([])", "{()[]}", "([)]", "{([)]}" ]

def check_braces(exps)
  m = { "{" => "}", "[" => "]", "(" => ")" }
  exps.each do |ex|
    el = []
    ex.chars.each do |char|
      char == m[el[-1]] ? el.pop : el.push(char)
    end
    puts (el.empty? ? 1 : 0)
  end
end

check_braces(expressions)
```